# How can I increase the space between elements in my blog using blogger?

Tags: html, padding, blogger, sidebar, margins

On my blog (http://www.ourunitedvoice.org/) all of the elements in both sidebars and event the blog posts are smashed so closely together. I'd like to create some padding/margins between each element so that they are not on top of each other!

Can someone tell me where/how to change this specifically in the HTML code? Thanks!

Comment: The space you have is optimum.If you increase the space, users with 1024 pixels wide resolution wont be able to see the sidebars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `<br/>` where ever you want a bit of extra space